# How to find out how many lines text wraps to in a TextView on Android?

Tags: android, string, text, textview, word-wrap

I have a long String that wraps to multiple lines, and that number of lines is different depending on the size of the Android device being used.  Is there a way to know how many lines the text wraps to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the [Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) classes:

```
Layout layout = new StaticLayout(text, /* other stuff--see docs */);
int nLines = layout.getLineCount();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in XML?

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac - I don't think so. At the time the xml is compiled, there's no way for the system to know the device characteristics on which it will run.